# Drupal lots of spam page not found errors in my watchdog logs

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404, spam, watchdog

I am getting a lot of (more than 10 every minute) of page not found errors similar to this example.

Type    page not found
Date    Friday, November 16, 2012 - 01:27
User    Anonymous (not verified)
Location    http://ad.yieldmanager.com/http://ad.yieldmanager.com/st?     ad_type=ad&ad_size=160x600&section=3704956
Referrer    http://www.hotfirstgames.com/shooting/915.html
Message ttp://ad.yieldmanager.com/st
Severity    warning
Hostname    173.254.197.131

there are a lot of hits which take a toll on my server. the ip address location and referrer keep changing.
what can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Are these requests legitimate at all? Why is someone making ad requests to your site? is it spammy? It helps to know how real they are.